# corosync fails to install

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I was trying to setup cluster using corosync and pacemaker on RHEL6 (CentOS release 6.5)

I have added following repo data

```
[haclustering]
name=HA Clustering
type=rpm-md
baseurl=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/ha-clustering:/Stable/RedHat_RHEL-6/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/ha-clustering:/Stable/RedHat_RHEL-6/repodata/repomd.xml.key
enabled=1
```

I was trying to install enabling repo by default (enabled=1) and with repo disabled and using --enablerepo option while installing pacemaker and corosync only.

It seems that there is problem with dependencies and I am having error messages as below:

```
Error: Package: pacemaker-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libcoroipcc.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libcoroipcc.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libcoroipcc.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: pacemaker-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libcfg.so.4(COROSYNC_CFG_0.82)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libcfg.so.4(COROSYNC_CFG_0.82)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libcfg.so.4(COROSYNC_CFG_0.82)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: pacemaker-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libconfdb.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libconfdb.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libconfdb.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: pacemaker-libs-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libconfdb.so.4(COROSYNC_CONFDB_1.0)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libconfdb.so.4(COROSYNC_CONFDB_1.0)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libconfdb.so.4(COROSYNC_CONFDB_1.0)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: pacemaker-cli-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libcoroipcc.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libcoroipcc.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libcoroipcc.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: pacemaker-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libconfdb.so.4(COROSYNC_CONFDB_1.0)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libconfdb.so.4(COROSYNC_CONFDB_1.0)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libconfdb.so.4(COROSYNC_CONFDB_1.0)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: pacemaker-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libcfg.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libcfg.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libcfg.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: clusterlib-3.0.12.1-59.el6_5.2.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libconfdb.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libconfdb.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libconfdb.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: clusterlib-3.0.12.1-59.el6_5.2.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libconfdb.so.4(COROSYNC_CONFDB_1.0)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libconfdb.so.4(COROSYNC_CONFDB_1.0)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libconfdb.so.4(COROSYNC_CONFDB_1.0)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: pacemaker-cli-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libcfg.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libcfg.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libcfg.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: pacemaker-libs-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libcoroipcc.so.4(COROSYNC_COROIPCC_3.0)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libcoroipcc.so.4(COROSYNC_COROIPCC_3.0)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libcoroipcc.so.4(COROSYNC_COROIPCC_3.0)(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: pacemaker-libs-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libcfg.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libcfg.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libcfg.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: pacemaker-libs-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libconfdb.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libconfdb.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libconfdb.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: pacemaker-libs-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libcoroipcc.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libcoroipcc.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libcoroipcc.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
Error: Package: pacemaker-cli-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a-1.1.x86_64 (haclustering)
           Requires: libconfdb.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libconfdb.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-1.4.1-17.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               libconfdb.so.4()(64bit)
           Available: corosynclib-2.3.3-1.1.i686 (haclustering)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any clue how to fix this problem? Is pacemaker-1.1.12 working for anyone installing from 'ha-clustering' repository?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience.  It seems that in the past, you could have used the OpenSUSE packages on CentOS.  But at least in their current incarnation, the dependencies are all screwed up.  If you use the current CentOS packages as the other answer suggests, you'll have to deal with CMAN too, not just Pacemaker and Corosync.  I'm not sure if that's what you were looking to do.

I was able to get a Pacemaker and Corosync 2.x cluster up by building the software from source on CentOS 6.5... but it wasn't a lot of fun.

Comment: If I remember well, on Centos 6.5 you need to use cman+pacemaker.

Comment: @c4f4t0r, you don't have to use cman, thankfully.   I mean, you would, if you accepted the default RHEL/centos packages.   But, you can start from source, or adapt the newer centos 7 packages for use on centos 6.

Comment: Better to start using centos 7 with a full supported stack corosync+pacemaker.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use anything from the Suse repo except `crmsh` and `pssh` so you should add a line to the repo file which says `includepkgs=crmsh,pssh` so that it does not overwrite the CentOS supplied corosync etc.

Add is this repo to your Centos Pacemaker Srv 1 and Srv2

```
[heartbeat]
name=HA Clustering
baseurl=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/ha-clustering:/Stable/CentOS_CentOS-6/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
includepkgs=crmsh,pssh
```